# Getting name+otherinfo out of querset django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get a dict out of a Queryset.
I have a query set called `showroom`.

When I just print showroom it gives this information.

```
<QuerySet [<LeadFormData: Lead form: testing 2 leadform>]>
```

When I use `shoowroom.values()` it shows me this.

```
<QuerySet [{'last_updated': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 9, 10, 5, 33, 182308), u'id': 5,'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 9, 10, 5, 33, 182296)}]>
```

I am trying to learn how filters work in a query set but I am not sure on how to get the information out of this above code and put it in a `dict` like this.

```
{u'testing 2 leadform': [{'count': 5, 'ts': datetime.date(2017, 10, 9)}, {'count': 0, 'ts': datetime.date(2017, 10, 9)}]}
```

Since I have to append to another dict which takes in the data in the above format.

This is what I have currently, I am no way sure on how to take out the name from the Queryset since the error I get is Querset does not contain .name

```
dictToStore = {}
for s in showroom:
dictToStore[s.name] = {'count' : s.id , 'ts':last_updated ,'ts' : last_updated}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values) which return the dict representation of the instance in the queryset.

> Returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries, rather than model instances, when used as an iterable.

Something like this:

```
qs = showroom.values()
```

Comment: I tried .values(), like I said on my post above, I don't get the name that I want. Since the query set has the name testing 2 leadform and when I do .values() it goes away